# C++, basics about inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

If I have derived class called `PeekingIterator`, and the base class call `Iterator`. The derived class re-use the members and member function of the base-class. Now in C++, inheritance doesn't inherit private member.

But in the example below, `struct Data` and `Data* data` are private member! So my question is: how can we call `Iterator::hasNext()` function inside the derived class `PeekingIterator`,  when it doesn't even inherits  `struct data` and `Data* data`!?

[Question Link](https://leetcode.com/problems/peeking-iterator/)

```
// Below is the interface for Iterator, which is already defined for you.
// **DO NOT** modify the interface for Iterator.
class Iterator {
    struct Data;
    Data* data;
public:
    Iterator(const vector<int>& nums);
    Iterator(const Iterator& iter);
    virtual ~Iterator();
    // Returns the next element in the iteration.
    int next();
    // Returns true if the iteration has more elements.
    bool hasNext() const;
};


class PeekingIterator : public Iterator {
public:
    PeekingIterator(const vector<int>& nums) : Iterator(nums) {
        // Initialize any member here.
        // **DO NOT** save a copy of nums and manipulate it directly.
        // You should only use the Iterator interface methods.

    }

    // Returns the next element in the iteration without advancing the iterator.
    int peek() {

    }

    // hasNext() and next() should behave the same as in the Iterator interface.
    // Override them if needed.
    int next() {

    }

    bool hasNext() const {

    }
```

Comment: I don't see the problem , calling `Iterator::hasNext()` should work fine .. what's the question ?

Comment: Inheritance DOES include inheriting private members.    They're just not accessible.  If you want the base class to affect them, either provide public/protected member functions to do required operations on them (which can be used by derived classes).  You can provide other functions which give a pointer or reference to private members (through which the privates can then be changed) but - if you do that - you might as well make the members public and be done with it.

Comment: Dumb question, if I declare `PeekingIterator  pi` in `main`, am I able to do call the base class function such as `pi.Iteratorr::hasNext()` ?

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance in c++ embeds an object of a base class into an object of a sub class. You inherit *everything*. You just can't *access* everything directly.

Now, since `hasNext()` is public, you can call it (and still could if it was protected). `hasNext()` itself can access the private parts of `Iterator` (which are added to `PeekingIterator` by `Iterator`). So everything will work.

Comment: Dumb question, if I declare `PeekingIterator  pi`, am I able to do `pi.Iteratorr::hasNext()` in the `main` ?

Comment: @Anni_housie Yes. That's how you'd call the base class function.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is: how can we call `Iterator::hasNext()` function inside the derived class `PeekingIterator`,  when it doesn't even inherits  `struct data` and `Data* data`!?

That's the basic of encapsulation - you keep the data private (`struct data`), but you expose public member function (`hasNext()`) so it can be accessed by derived classes.

Comment: Dumb question, if I declare `PeekingIterator  pi` in `main`, am I able to do call the base class function such as `pi.Iteratorr::hasNext()` ?

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator::hasNext()` can be called from any function in `PeekingIterator`. For example:

```
bool PeekingIterator::hasNext() {
   bool b = Iterator::hasNext();
   ....
 }
```